# Linux Distros with Path

Tags: upgrade, distributions

Which Linux Distros have like do-release-upgrade like in Ubuntu where you can upgrade to a newer version without a new clean install with USB i have been checking Zorin OS and Elementary OS but they all say you have to do a clean install with a USB is Ubuntu the only distro where you can do-release-upgrade in the terminal?

Comment: Most of the "classic" distros do. The only ones that don't are ones that aren't really used in production I would imagine. In any case, there are way too many distros to list the ones that do and the ones that don't. If you're starting out, stick to the major distros and everything'll be fine.

Comment: @Ginnungagap Can i see which Distros that are in production somehow? It is over 600 linux distros out there :(

Comment: Stick to Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS or RHEL for starters, they're the major distros out there and all have thought-out upgrade paths. If you want something more exotic, feel free to try it out but you'll have plenty of support for the ones I listed.

Comment: Thanks @Ginnungagap

Comment: Simply put `/home` on a different partition than `/`, and, with care, you can upgrade to your heart's content.

Comment: @waltinator that is cute in theory, but in practice having intact user data is a bit useless when you can't boot anymore, for example.